# django - generate CREATE TABLE sql for models

Tags: django, django-migrations

Is there any way in django to generate the CREATE TABLE script for my models for a particular DB engine? (MySQL in my case)

Answer (score 4):

you can use command in console

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> migration_name
```

where migration name is the name of file with migration that you need.
e.g.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate manager 0001_initial
```

Comment: thanks! that's useful. But what if the table has been created and modified in many migrations? I guess I just can temporarily delete all migrations, create a new migration for everything, and then run this and extract the table I want.